# Asio. Error: "The I/o operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application requests"

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio, asio

I am trying to create an async server using **asio** but when the acceptor calls async_accept function, I get this error **The I/o operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application requests**, which doesn't let the process continue. I have tried to change the port but it doesn't work. When I try to make a sync server so it works.
Also I use **asio** as a separate lib from boost.

Here's the function where I get the error:

```
void startAsyncAccept()
    {
        acceptor.async_accept(socket, [&](const asio::error_code& error)
            {
                if(!error)
                {
                    std::cout << "Client is connected" << "\n";
                    startAsyncRead();
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    std::cerr << "It is: " << error.message() << '\n';
                    return 0;
                    
                }
                startAsyncAccept();


            }
        );
        
    }
```

Ans here's my async server:

```
class Server
{
public:
    Server(asio::io_context& io_context) : acceptor(io_context, asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 2000)), socket(io_context)
    {
        startAsyncAccept();
    }
    ~Server() {}
private:
    // Members
    asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor;
    asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
    asio::streambuf buffer;
    std::vector<asio::ip::tcp::socket> sockets;

    // Functions
    void startAsyncAccept()
    {
        acceptor.async_accept(socket, [&](const asio::error_code& error)
            {
                if(!error)
                {
                    std::cout << "Client is connected" << "\n";
                    startAsyncRead();
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    std::cerr << "It is: " << error.message() << '\n';
                    return 0;
                    
                }
                startAsyncAccept();


            }
        );
        
    }

    void startAsyncRead()
    {
        asio::async_read_until(socket, buffer, '\n', [&](const asio::error_code& error, size_t length)
            {
                if(!error)
                {
                    std::string message(asio::buffers_begin(buffer.data()), asio::buffers_begin(buffer.data()) + length);
                    std::cout << "Received from client: " << message;

                    for(auto& clients : sockets)
                    {
                        asio::async_write(clients, asio::buffer(message), [&](const asio::error_code& error, size_t length) 
                            {
                                if(error)
                                {
                                    std::cerr << "Failed to write to client: " << error.message() << "\n";
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }
                    buffer.consume(length);
                    startAsyncRead();

                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Client disconnected." << std::endl;
                    removeClient();
                }
            }
        );
    }

    void startAsyncWrite() 
    {
        asio::async_write(socket, asio::buffer("Connected to chat Server. \n"), [&](const asio::error_code& error, size_t length) 
            {
                if(error)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Failed to write to the client: " << error.message() << "\n";
                    removeClient();
                }
            }
        );
    }
    void removeClient()
    {
        auto it = std::find_if(sockets.begin(), sockets.end(),
            [&](const auto& client_socket)
            {
                return &client_socket == &socket;
            });

        if (it != sockets.end())
        {
            sockets.erase(it);
        }
    }


};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there's [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the lambda misses a return on some paths. This seems to be a copy-paste error of some sort, so I'll just remove the `return 0;` that was meaningless.

### The Real Problem

The real problem is that you use the same `socket` on each accept. That means that you reset the socket that you started the first `asyncRead` on as soon as you call `startAsyncAccept` again. That causes the `asio::error::operation_aborted` error code.

Simply don't use the same socket. Move it into a "session" object e.g. Or, as you seem to have wanted to do, put them in your collection of `sockets`.

### Fixing?

Ironically, it is hard to know how you wanted to use `sockets` since it is literally unused in your current code (except for the loops that will never iterate, because `sockets` is always empty).

What's worse, it's only good that didn't work, because otherwise you get more [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because `std::vector` will reallocate to grow capacity, meaning that any references to existing sockets are invalidated.

The usual way to deal with this is *not* to have a collection of sockets, but rather collection of (weak) shared pointers to sessions objects. For simplicity, let me fix the reference stability here by changing `std::vector` to `std::list` and removing the problematic `socket` variable.

```
tcp::socket              socket;
asio::streambuf          buffer;
std::vector<tcp::socket> sockets;
```

Becomes

```
asio::streambuf        buffer;
std::list<tcp::socket> sockets;
```

There's big problems as well with `async_write` as

- you use a local variable `message` as the buffer. This is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) again, because its lifetime ends before the write operations complete
- you MUST avoid overlapping calls. Because you don't control when `async_read_until` completes (and you might have an arbitrary number of connected clients), you cannot be sure no writes overlap. The only solution there is to have an "outbox" queue - typically per client, for independent operation of each connection.

As a sidenote, it's unclear what `startAsyncWrite` was supposed to do (it was unused, and doesn't help to solve the problem just described). Same with `removeClient` which would never do anything even if you **had** filled `sockets`, it would just cause [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to the invalidation of socket references. I dropped those two for now.

Finally, you use a streambuf, where it seems you might just use a dynamic string buffer directly. In any case, put the `consume` closer to the "consume" so that you don't risk missing it under some error condition.

### Simplified V1

This simplified version removes the problems that you ask about as well as the lifetime of the `message`:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77dcf924ef2d3d72)**

```
class Server {
  public:
    Server(asio::io_context& io_context) //
        : acceptor(io_context, {{}, 2000}) {
        startAsyncAccept();
    }

  private:
    // Members
    tcp::acceptor          acceptor;
    asio::streambuf        buffer;
    std::list<tcp::socket> sockets;

    void startAsyncAccept() {
        acceptor.async_accept([&](error_code error, tcp::socket accepted) {
            if (!error) {
                auto& client = sockets.emplace_back(std::move(accepted));
                std::cout << "Client is connected\n";
                startAsyncRead(client);
            } else {
                std::cerr << "It is: " << error.message() << "\n";
            }
            startAsyncAccept();
        });
    }

    void startAsyncRead(tcp::socket& client) {
        asio::async_read_until(client, buffer, '\n', [&](error_code error, size_t n) {
            if (!error) {
                auto f = asio::buffers_begin(buffer.data()), l = f + static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(n);
                auto message = std::make_shared<std::string>(f, l);
                buffer.consume(n);
                std::cout << "Received from client: " << message;

                for (auto& peer : sockets) {
                    // SEHE: TODO FIXME serializing writes per peer!
                    asio::async_write(
                        peer, asio::buffer(*message), [&, message](error_code error, size_t /*length*/) {
                            if (error) {
                                std::cerr << "Failed to write to client: " << error.message() << "\n";
                            }
                        });
                }
                startAsyncRead(client);
            } else {
                std::cout << "Client disconnected." << std::endl;
                // SEHE: TODO ERASE
            }
        });
    }
};
```

### Fixed: Client Sessions

Some more work to fix the other problems:

[after breakfast]

**UPDATE** You absolutely need a separate `Session`, because I missed earlier (before breakfast) that you were also falsely using the same `streambuf` instance for all connections... A `Session` type makes for a logical place to group the incoming buffer, outgoing buffer queue and socket.

We use `enable_shared_from_this` together with `shared_from_this()` to get automatic lifetime management when a connection gets bad/closed.

Note that it all comes down to correct [Separation Of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns): The Server manages the listening, the ChatRoom manages connected clients, the Session manages a single client.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67a8e33acbdb2bb4)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#ifndef STANDALONE_ASIO
    namespace asio = boost::asio;
    using boost::system::error_code;
#else
    using asio::error_code;
#endif
using asio::ip::tcp;

struct Session;
using SessionPtr = std::shared_ptr<Session>;
using Handle     = std::weak_ptr<Session>;

struct ChatRoom {
    std::list<Handle> clients_;

    void garbage_collect();
    void broadcast(std::string_view message);

    // just for example:
    void direct_message(std::string recipient, std::string_view message);
};

struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
    Session(tcp::socket s, ChatRoom& room) : socket_(std::move(s)), room_(room) {}
    void start() { readLoop(); }

    void send(std::string_view message){
        outbox_.emplace_back(message);
        if (outbox_.size() == 1)
            writeLoop();
    }

  private:
    tcp::socket             socket_;
    ChatRoom&               room_;
    asio::streambuf         incoming_;
    std::deque<std::string> outbox_;

    void readLoop() {
        asio::async_read_until(
            socket_, incoming_, '\n', [&, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                if (ec) {
                    std::cout << "Client disconnect (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
                    return;
                }

                auto f = asio::buffers_begin(incoming_.data()), l = f + static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(n);
                room_.broadcast(std::string(f, l));
                incoming_.consume(n);

                readLoop();
            });
    }

    void writeLoop() {
        if (outbox_.empty())
            return;

        asio::async_write( //
            socket_, asio::buffer(outbox_.front()),
            [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t /*length*/) {
                outbox_.pop_front();
                if (ec)
                    std::cerr << "Failed to write to client: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                else
                    writeLoop();
            });
    }
};

class Server {
  public:
    Server(asio::any_io_executor ex) : acceptor_(ex, {{}, 2000}) { acceptLoop(); }

  private:
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    ChatRoom      room_;

    void acceptLoop() {
        room_.garbage_collect(); // optionally prevent dead connections piling up

        acceptor_.async_accept([&](error_code ec, tcp::socket accepted) {
            if (!ec) {
                auto sess = std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(accepted), room_);
                room_.clients_.push_back(sess);
                std::cout << "Client is connected\n";

                sess->start();
            } else {
                std::cerr << "Accept error: " << ec.message() << "\n";
            }
            acceptLoop();
        });
    }
};

void ChatRoom::garbage_collect() {
    clients_.remove_if(std::mem_fn(&Handle::expired));
}

void ChatRoom::broadcast(std::string_view message) {
    for (auto& handle : clients_) {
        if (auto peer = handle.lock()) {
            peer->send(message);
        }
    }
}

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
int main() {
    asio::io_context io;
    Server chat(io.get_executor());

    io.run_for(30s);
}
```

Testing with a number of clients:

```
for a in {1..10}; do (
        sleep 1.$RANDOM
        echo "hello from $a"
        sleep 1.$RANDOM
        echo "bye from $a"
) | nc 127.0.0.1 2000 -w3 | (while read line; do echo "Client $a received '$line'"; done) & done
```

Prints output like:

[image]

Also live on Coliru :)

Comment: Added the properly organized demo, turns out I even missed another problem so you absolutely needed that fix too

Comment: PS. I've assumed you're running the server on a single IO thread, like in my example. Otherwise you need strands for synchronization.