# C++ Boost Asio removal storage Sesion connection in vector in Server

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have two combined problems

1. I don't know how to terminate in func read if it doesn't receive any data terminate the connection and notify the server.
2. With removing the class Session from the `m_storageSession` vector located in the class server after it finishes receivinchog data
   `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Session>> m_StorageSession`;

```
void Server::startAcceptNewConnectionAsync()
{
    m_Acceptor.async_accept(
        [this](boost::system::error_code aError_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket aSocket)
        {
            if (!aError_code)
            {
                
                boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = aSocket.remote_endpoint();

                std::shared_ptr<SessionEchoBoost> newSession = std::make_shared<SessionEchoBoost>
                    (this, m_SessionID.GetFreeID(), endpoint.address().to_string(),
                        endpoint.port(), std::move(aSocket));
                newSession->start();
                
                m_StorageSession.push_back(newSession);
            }
            startAcceptNewConnectionAsync();
        });
}
```

```
void Server::notificationAbautCloseConnectionSession(const size_t& theIdSession)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_StorageSession.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (m_StorageSession[i]->getIdSession() == theIdSession)
        {
      m_SessionID.DeleteSession(m_StorageSession[i]->getIdSession());
      m_StorageSession[i]->close();
      break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
Session::~Session()
{
    if (m_Owner)
    {
        m_Owner->notificationAbautCloseConnectionSession(m_IdSession); // Server*m_Owner 
    }
}
```

```
void Session::do_read()
{
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    m_Socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(m_FrameCommunicationDataIn.getBuforData() + m_FrameCommunicationDataIn.getIndexSaveDataInBuffor(), m_FrameCommunicationDataIn.getSizeBufforData()),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                if (length != 0)
                {
                    m_FrameCommunicationDataIn.setAmauntCopyDataIn(length);
                    newDataFromSession();
                   
                }
                else
                {
                   
                this->~Session();    
                }
                do_read();
            }
        });
}
```

I would like the session to notify the server that it has finished receiving the data and the server removes it from the vector.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using weak_ptr, as your sessions are already using shared pointers.

That way you can avoid the tight coupling: the server can just detect expired sessions.

About ending the session: the fact that your async operations capture `self` causes it to stick around. If you don't post any new async operation, implicitly the `Session` will get destructed.

I would show you how to edit your example, but it isn't self contained. So instead look at a number of my answers doing very similar things:

- [Boost Beast Async Websocket Server How to interface with session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71638897/boost-beast-async-websocket-server-how-to-interface-with-session/71640691#71640691)
- [Asynchronous tcp server using boost's async_write results in bad file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65285735/asynchronous-tcp-server-using-boosts-async-write-results-in-bad-file-descriptor/65293552#65293552)
- [Server crashing while being interrupted sending large chunk of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71744762/server-crashing-while-being-interrupted-sending-large-chunk-of-data/71745354#71745354) (which has the session logic separate in a ConnectionManager)
- [Asio. Error: "The I/o operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application requests"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76832126/asio-error-the-i-o-operation-has-been-aborted-because-of-either-a-thread-exit/76835115#76835115)
- [How to eliminate crashes when destroying boost::asio entities on fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711285/how-to-eliminate-crashes-when-destroying-boostasio-entities-on-fly/63711994#63711994)

You will be able to find more searching for `expired` `weak_ptr` `remove_if` etc.